# Tricking a javascript code to think it has a focused window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, focus

How it is possible to make a javascript code think that it has a focused window (but actually it does not has a focused window)?

-

Edited: I think by using [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL) (in a Firefox extension) we can inject CSS to pages

Comment: why does something need to be focused?

Comment: Focusing on the window isn't really something JS can do, as a child of said window. The browser can (and might) suspend the entire window, including JS, which you can't really respond to.

Comment: @ssube I do not want to focus window by JS, I want to develop a browser extension, which when you use it all the tabs in the browser think that they are selected (for example by hooking JS functions)

Comment: @Iman, "all the tabs think they are selected"? There will be only one selected tab in each window..

Comment: Do you mean forcefully set the `:focused` pseudo class on a window? This can be done in Firefox but only by an addon.

Comment: @HaibaraAi Everyone know that, I want to override that behavior and change it

Comment: @Noitidart Do you know the how we can code that in a Firefox extension?

Comment: @Iman I added it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a firefox addon, if you want to set the `:focused` css pseudo-class of a window, get the DOMWindow and use `iniDOMUtils` method of `addPseudoClassLock`:

```
var inIDOMUtils = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/inspector/dom-utils;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.inIDOMUtils);
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
inIDOMUtils.addPseudoClassLock(win, ':focused');
```

To remove it, use `removePseudoClassLock`.

If you are Firefox addon dev this note below is common sense, but I'll mention it just in case you aren't familiar with Firefox addon dev:

This is privileged code, so you have to run it from privileged scope. You cannot run this code in content scripts obviously (as that would be equivalent of running it in a webpage scope).